How does Shizuku work?
I understand it offers elevated privileges to apps on unrooted devices. Since my current device is unrooted,  I investigated a bit and found that quite a few apps support it. Some app developers shun Shizuku and prefer adb.
This lead me to bunch of inter-related questions:

How exactly does it work?
Why do some app developers support only adb (don't entertain Shizuku), some both and Shizuku and adb
What are the pros and cons over adb?
Are there any security implications in using Shizuku?

I am aware that SE expects a question to be focused on one topic but I believe that all these are related in understanding the working of Shizuku, as in title and would not lead to closing the question!

[tag:Shizuku] tag wiki excerpt is empty now and hopefully answers can help in making an excerpt.

When you say "support only adb" I'm a bit confused are you referring to apps that use different privileges available under adb and root?

@MorrisonChang sorry for the confusion. don't mean varying levels of privileges with adb/Shizuku/root. There are apps that only entertain adb (root of course) but don't allow privileges with Shizuku. I am interested in the reasoning behind that. Is it only reasons such as these

Apps want to use Android's privileged APIs to offer extra functionality which is not possible with Android's standard SDK APIs. So they need root or ADB privileges. Shizuku acts as a proxy between apps and Android's privileged APIs. For users: they don't have to provide root/ADB to multiple apps. For app developers: they don't have to deal with root/ADB. Big convenience. But access to privileged APIs is not the only thing apps want with root/ADB. Many apps just need to run shell commands. And the started process might have been designed to do more complex things other than just accessing ...

... the privileged APIs, e.g. processing data obtained from Android, and then holding it on behalf of the app, and provide the required info when needed. This is not possible with Shizuku. Also, dealing with the visibility of non-SDK APIs is an extra task when accessed through Shizuku. But no extra measure is to be taken when accessed from a process running with root/ADB privileges. So, for simple cases Shizuku is great. But for complex designs, depending on a third party service for the core functionality of an app might not be a good design choice from every developers' perspective.

@IrfanLatif: hard to digest(for me) without concrete examples addressing all Qs. Thanks anyway

That's why I ended with "from a developer's perspective". From a user's perspective, it may not make much sense.


It runs a background process with root/ADB privileges. Apps talk to this privileged process. The process talks to Android framework. // 2. Answered in the previous comments. // 3. Convenience. None. // 4. None as long as Shizuku is open-source (this applies to every app which uses root/ADB).


Point 1 as you put it, root/ADB. Shizuku= ADB only right

No. It supports both root and ADB.
